# Platform independent protobuf socket protocol - what message will I receive?

Tags: c#, sockets, network-protocols, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am preparing to write a platform independent socket protocol. After some initial research protobuf seems the way to go. I am new to protobuf and I can't seem to figure out one specific issue.

My requirements are:

- Completely platform independent client;
- C# server;
- Async message communication;
- Work from a `.proto` file (so no inference from existing classes);
- Must be able to send messages without the server/client knowing up front which message type to expect.

I have already found the `(De)SerializeWithLengthPrefix` methods, and they are a start. **What I can't figure out is how to receive a message if I do not know the type up front.**

I have already seen that protobuf-net supports inheritance and can detect the type of the message, so for protobuf-net, inheriting all messages from a common base type would work. **However, this is not platform independent and I am looking for a platform independent way of doing this.**

**So my question is: how do I send my messages so that any client can deserialize them without knowing the type up front?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the requirement is to work with multiple messages of different types:

Just associate a unique number with each different type of message, and use as a prefix to the message; you can do this trivially with the optional integer parameter to the overloaded `SerializeWithLengthPrefix` method. The client would have to pre-process this prefix (or it can be handled within protobuf-net by `Serializer.NonGeneric`, which has a deserialization method that provides a callback for obtaining the type from this prefix number).

---

If the requirement is to work with **completely unknown data**:

Given you requirements, I *suspect* [Jon's port](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/) would be a better fit; since your emphasis is on platform independence and .proto, and not on inference (where protobuf-net excels) or other .NET specific extensions / utilities.

Note that while a .proto *can* be compiled (via protoc) to a regular protobuf stream, working with entirely foreign data at the receiver is... irregular. It can probably be done by treating everything as extensions or by working with the coded streams, but...

---

Edit following discussion in comments:

A simple schema here could be simply:

```
message BaseMessage {
    optional SomeMessage someMessage = 1;
    optional SomeOtherMessage someOtherMessage = 2;
    optional SomeThirdMessage someThirdMessage = 3;
}
message SomeMessage {...}
message SomeOtherMessage {...}
message SomeThirdMessage {...}
```

(you could optionally add a discriminator, if that helps)

This is actually *essentially* how protobuf-net treats *inheritance*, but is easily represented from other clients, and handles everything like lengths of sub-messages automatically.

Comment: I think I may not have been clear in my question. If will have the .proto file and a normal protobuf implementation at the client, so I will have the classes and such. The only problem I have is how to decide the type of the receiving message. With protobuf-net, I can do this with inheritance, but how do I do this in a platform independent manner. Maybe I didn't understand your answer, but I can't really place the "foreign data at the receiver."

Comment: @Pieter - I figured that out - see my edit; to be explicit, I think inheritance is very much the wrong approach here. Let me know if you want more detail, but the approach is actually pretty basic - if necessary it could be a `switch` at the client.

Comment: OK, but that does mean that I will have to parse the prefix myself because I cannot use `DeserializeWithPrefixLength` anymore. Is that correct? I would expect something like a `TryReadLengthPrefix` **`AndTag`** for this.

Comment: @Pieter - inside protobuf-net, the `Serializer.NonGeneric` version allows exactly what you need. Note that you would need to check what is available in *other* clients - for example, if you have to handle the length yourself, it may be easiest to work with fixed-length LE/BE for the length. Another thought has occurred, though - see the *next* edit ;p

Comment: The `BaseMessage` approach looks great. I suspect that on the wire, only the message that's actually set is serialized? And I suspect that this is platform independent? The only thing is: I will have to prefix the messages with a length anyway because of the socket usage. I would have to implement that in other clients anyway. I guess just adding the tag too would probably be easiest. What do you think would be the best approach?

Comment: @Pieter - yes, as long as you leave the rest as `null`, nothing will get serialized for the other fields. If it helps, this is **exactly** protobuf-net inheritance, so you could decorate with `ProtoInclude` (but only if that helps).

Comment: @Pieter - re the length; to be honest, any approach will work; I wouldn't over-analyse...